# AVAudioRecorder and audio data file offset of wav audio file

Tags: ios, swift, macos, avfoundation

wav file afinfo command give the audio data offset as 4096, Is there any way to change data offset to 44 on macOS or iOS using AVFoundation

my setting as follows

```
func exportSettings() -> Dictionary <String, Any> {

    var recordingSetting :[String:Any] = [AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16, AVNumberOfChannelsKey : 1, AVSampleRateKey : 16_000, AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey : 0, AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey : 0]
    recordingSetting[AVFormatIDKey] = Int(kAudioFormatLinearPCM)
    recordingSetting[AVChannelLayoutKey] = NSData(bytes: nil, length: 0)
    recordingSetting[AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved] = 0
    return recordingSetting
}
```

thanks